# Create Roles and Manage Users in terms of Roles in a WPF app

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, membership-provider, roleprovider

I have been reading many articles about membership and role management in asp.net. What I would like to do is to apply it to a wpf application. I am using the membership in System.Web.Security. It's working well. Now I just need to add Roles.
I have used aspnet_regsql.exe to create the tables in my database. I know I need to change my app.config for me to be able to create and use Roles in my app.

If someone could direct me to any tutorials or examples or any walk through that implements role management in a wpf app then it will really be of great help.

Thank you in advance